# Can we predict something about the automorphism of an abelian group of order $315$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, automorphism-group

> Can we predict something about the automorphism of an abelian group of order $315$?

I know that $ \mbox{Aut}(\mathbb{Z_3} \times \mathbb{Z_3}) = \mbox{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z_3})$ and $|\mbox{Aut}(\mathbb{Z_9})| = \varphi(9)$ where $\varphi(9)$ is the euler toitent's function.

Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $315$ then $G \cong \mathbb{Z_3} \times \mathbb{Z_3} \times \mathbb{Z_7} \times \mathbb{Z_5}$ or $G \cong \mathbb{Z_9}  \times \mathbb{Z_7} \times \mathbb{Z_5}$

Now in the second case I guess $Aut(G) \cong (\mathbb{Z_9})^* \times \mathbb{Z_7}^* \times \mathbb{Z_5}^*$

What about the first case?

Comment: In the first case $Aut(G)$ is again the direct product of the automorphism groups. This is a simple exercise since the Sylow $p$-subgroups are unique.

Comment: I should add [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2138170/autg-times-h-is-isomorphic-to-the-direct-product-autg-times-auth) for clarity.

Comment: Note that $GL_2(\Bbb F_3)$ has $48$ elements, but $(\Bbb Z/3)^*\times (\Bbb Z/3)^*$ has only $4$ elements. So this cannot be equal.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $Aut(G \times H) \cong Aut(G) \times Aut(H)$ but $\mathbb{Z_3}$ ,$ \mathbb{Z_3}$ are not groups of mutually prime order.

Comment: I don't understand the point of closing this question, the post associated also doesn't make sense.I have no idea of endomorphism stuffs

Comment: Do you still have a question now?

Comment: Yes, I do .So what is Aut(G) in the first case is it isomorphic to $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3) \times Aut(\mathbb{Z}_7) \times Aut(\mathbb{Z}_5)$?

Comment: Yes, right, exactly as you said in your post, and what the duplicate is saying.  It is isomorphic to $GL_2(\Bbb F_3)\times {\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z/7)\times  {\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z/5)$.

Comment: Is  $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3) \times Aut(\mathbb{Z}_7) \times Aut(\mathbb{Z}_5)$ isomorphic to $Gl_2(\mathbb{Z_3}) \times Aut(\mathbb{Z}_7) \times Aut(\mathbb{Z}_5)$ ?

Comment: Okay I understand now...

Comment: Very good, I am glad I could help.